# Regular Expression to get a string between backtick `` in Console application (C#)

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am trying to *parse* SQL by using *regular expression* in order to return *aliases* (a string after keyword `AS` between backtick ``). For instance for the input

```
 var test = "select t.`ProductID` AS `ProductID`, t.`AttributeID` AS `AttributeID`, t.`String_Value` AS `String_Value`, t.`Numeric_Value` AS `Numeric_Value`, t.`MetaData` AS `MetaData`, t.`DataType` AS `DataType`, t.`CreatedTime` AS `CreatedTime`, t.`CreatedBy` AS `CreatedBy`, t.`ModifiedTime` AS `ModifiedTime`, t.`ModifiedBy` from dfsfile.tmp1.my_json t";
```

the expected return is

```
"ProductID",
"AttributeID",
"String_Value",
"Numeric_Value",
"MetaData",
"DataType",
"CreatedTime",
"CreatedBy",
"ModifiedTime"
```

Comment: Where are you stuck then?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:- I am new in regular expression. from `test` i want to print text after AS i.e:- ProductID, AttributeID. But i don't know how to write regar expression syntax for that.

Comment: Use this regex: `/ AS \`([^\`]*)\`/g` and print value of captured group #1 in a `while` loop.

Comment: @Tushar:- if i use `/AS\s+`([^`]*)`/g` it giving `AS `ProductID`,AS `AttributeID`,AS `String_Value`,AS `Numeric_Value`,AS `MetaData`,AS `DataType`,AS `CreatedTime`,AS `CreatedBy`,AS `ModifiedTime``. but i want to print `ProductID,AttributeID,Numeric_Value, etc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (*Regular expression* and *Linq*):

```
 String test = "select t.`ProductID` AS `ProductID`, t.`AttributeID` ...";

 // If you want to preserve `` the pattern is @"\bAS\s*(`[^`]*?`)"
 String pattern = @"\bAS\s*`([^`]*?)`";     

 var result = Regex
    .Matches(test, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToArray(); // if you want, say, an array representation

 Console.Write(String.Join(", ", result));
```

And you'll get

```
  ProductID, AttributeID, ... , ModifiedBy
```

However, be careful: in *general case* regular expressions are not a *good choice* for parsing `SQL`; let me provide some examples to show the problems emerging:

```
  -- commented AS ("abc" should not be returned)
  select a /* AS `abc`*/
    from tbl 

  -- commented value ("abc" should be returned, not "obsolete" or "proposed")
  select a AS /*`obsolete`*/ `abc` /*`proposed`*/
    from tbl 

  -- String ("abc" should not be returned)
  select 'a AS `abc`'
    from tbl

  -- honest AS ("abc" should be returned)
  select a /*'*/AS `abc`--'
    from tbl

  -- commented comment ("abc" should be returned)
  select -- /*
        a AS `abc`
        --*/
   from tbl
```

Comment: :- Thank sir its working for me. But you miss `@` symbol in ` String report = String.Join(", ", Regex.Matches(test, @"\bAS\s*`([^`]*?)`", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).OfType<Match>().Select(match => match.Groups[1].Value));`

Comment: @Sanjiv: I see; I'm sorry for the typo.

Comment: :- Is it possible to print output with backtick eg:- `'ProductID','AttributeID'`

Comment: @Sanjiv: yes, just put `` *within* the parenthesis `@"\bAS\s*(`[^`]*?`)"`

Comment: :- Didn't get you?

Comment: @Sanjiv: I've edited the answer then; in comment `` are treated as a code/plain text separator

Comment: @Sanjiv: if you want just to *printout* values, try formatting: `Console.Write(String.Join(", ", result.Select(item => string.Format("'{0}'", item))));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122829/discussion-between-sanjiv-and-dmitry-bychenko).

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychenko:- i don't want to print 'ProductId' but i want to print ProductID with backtick

Comment: @Sanjiv: either use pattern commented (see the edited answer) or formatting (I've put apostroph `'` as a back tick substitutor on that very purpose to show where aactual backticks should be: SO uses backtick as a code marker and thus distorts the comment)